# Why images inline css (base64) appear in the list of requests?

Tags: performance, httpwebrequest, base64, css-sprites

To try to minimize the number of requests in my application, I use base64 for small images in my css files.

But viewing the requests to the Google Chrome Developer, see each image generates a request.

Why this? How do these images do not generate these requests?

[image: Google Developer, request for base64 images]

This is my application: [dev.bindsolution.com](http://dev.bindsolution.com)

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the dev tools information. A row does not necessarily correspond to an \*HTTP\* request.

Comment: What format should the answer to this question take? "Why do they show up in the list? Because...they do." Why do you care? Perhaps the images go through a common code path internally (so that they will fire `onload` events. Do you really need to know why they are here? Or did you really mean to ask something else (like how to make them not show up, or whether this was affecting browser speed, or...)? +1 for including a screenshot and test code, but -1 for not asking a clear question.

Comment: They're using DATA urls, which means the actual "response" to that "request" can be embedded inside the same page that the data url is being used in.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL  `Method=Get`

I know that each does not not necessarily mean a request.
But a **GET request** means, right?

Comment: @Phrogz The fact that they are appearing on the list, involves performance, since each image is a request.

My question is why a request is made to an image base64? It should **not** be listed as 'GET', because it is as inline (base64)!

Sorry about the format of the question, my English is not fluent and it is a little hard for me to form a question in English.

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa why should it not be a GET? Read the whole line and you see that it GETs the image from the cache. Don't assume it is a HTTP-request over the wire.

Comment: @Marc B Sorry, but I'm kind of lay this matter. This means that a request was made? Or not?
I have a performance problem, and how can see in link dev.bindsolution.com, there are several request for images base64 (DATA)

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo yes, but as these images are base64 should not even be in cache does not agree? These images are inline in a CSS file.
(PS: I read all the lines, I know that these images are cached, and if you press Ctrl + F5 will see that a request be made for each image base64!)

Comment: Whatever's causing that probably looks like `<img src="data;image/gif;base64,xxxxxxxx">` in your raw html source. There's no external request made, as all the necessary data (the image's raw bits) are already embedded in that data url.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's just Chromium's implementation details leaking through into the UI (which is kind of expected, because the Developer Tools are there to view those very details). No server request is being made, a data URL is just handled as a request just like any other, because that's the most simple way to implement something like that in an existing request-response infrastructure.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know if a request was being done and why it is appearing on the list of Google Chrome as a resource GET. Now I understand!